How can I properly render gui in my dockerized alpine container
I'm trying to run alpine inside docker container with GUI. So I'm using the following command
docker run -it --env="DISPLAY" --net=host --name ostestalpine alpine

Inside the container, I'm installing firefox and other necessary tools. And when I'm launching firefox it's launching but, all the texts are being rendered is some weird way, most probably with unicode representation only. Please check this image:

How can I fix this?

This doesn't seem like it's programming-related; if it is, can you [edit] the question to include whatever source code you've written?  Also see Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?  If your problem is font rendering, then this may be using the font files in the container and not fonts that exist on the host.  Similar complexities exist up and down the stack, and I'd just run the browser and other desktop apps directly on the host system.

Resolved it by installing fonts:
apk --update --upgrade --no-cache add fontconfig ttf-freefont font-noto term
inus-font \
    && fc-cache -f \
    && fc-list | sort

If you want to add custom fonts, try adding them under /usr/share/fonts/Additional
references

https://github.com/orzih/mkdocs-with-pdf/blob/c97272aa92440789de2d93a6e78ae42b9c441eef/docker/mkdocs-with-pdf/alpine/Dockerfile#L25-L29
https://github.com/orzih/mkdocs-with-pdf/issues/50#issuecomment-767140386

